# SSL certificates not being generated with Certbot for Nginx when using Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, certbot

If I understand this correctly what you are required to do is to have a web server being hosted at a specific domain and then execute the certbot command with specific arguments.

I have created a directory in my VPS named `live` under that I created the following,

- `docker-compose.yml`
- `web/Dockerfile`
- `web/index.html`
- `config/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`
- `letsencrypt/`

Inside `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: "./web"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    container_name: "web"
    volumes:
      - "./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
  certbot:
    image: "certbot/certbot"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt"
    command: certonly
```

Inside `default.conf`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        allow all;
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```

I first try to build `docker compose build web`, then `docker compose up -d web`, checking on my domain I see the website hosting my simple `index.html` just fine.

Running the `docker compose run certbot` will execute the setup script, at some point it requests me to put a `--webroot` path which when I enter `/usr/share/nginx/html` doesn't seem to work, which I don't understand.